# Show this sentence is not a consequence of these 3 preconditions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The sentence is:
$$p=\forall x\forall e\forall u(u\in w(x,e)\leftrightarrow(u\in x \vee u=e)).$$

The preconditions are:

1. $\forall v$ $\neg v\in \emptyset$
2. $\forall e\forall u(u\in w(\emptyset, e)\leftrightarrow u=e)$
3. $\forall x \forall y \exists d ((d\in x \leftrightarrow d\in y)\rightarrow x=y)  $

If we consider a theory $\Sigma$ made out of 1. 2. and 3., is $\Sigma$ complete?

To answer this we need to prove the first part: $\Sigma \not\vdash p$, then if we prove $\Sigma\not\vdash\neg p$ we are done. How do we begin?

Comment: So the language consists of a binary predicate $\in$, a binary function $w$, and a constant letter $\emptyset$?

Comment: What is the difference between "$p$ is not a consequence of 1,2,3" and "$\Sigma\not\vdash p$"? You speak about them as if they were different "parts", but they seem to be to be exactly the same, just written either with words or with symbols.

Comment: Have you already shown that $\Sigma$ doesn't prove $\neg p$? How did you do that?

Comment: Sorry I've just misexplained myself, I'm editing the text so it is clear what I'm asking.

Comment: If you have any idea or resolution for this exercise, please be sure to answer.

Comment: Okay that's really usefull thanks! But if you comment without answering I can't rate you.

Comment: You're right; moved to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some further hints. (If the task is just to show that $\Sigma$ is not complete, then looking at $p$ in particular is already a hint ...)

Showing that $\Sigma\not\vdash\neg p$ is probably the conceptually most straightforward part. You'd need to show a model of $\Sigma$ where $\neg p$ is false -- that is, simply, a model of $\{1,2,3,p\}$. The symbols chosen ought to give you some idea what you might try to use for a model ...

Next, you can *modify* that model such that it doesn't satisfy $p$ anymore, but still satisfies $\Sigma$. The key observation here is that neither of 1,2,3 even speak about $w(x,y)$ when $x$ is something different from $\emptyset$, so you have great latitude to mess with what the interpretation of $w$ does, and make $p$ fail.